# Correct syntax for mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error with the following `PHP` statement:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (to, from, msg, field, date)  
VALUES ('TEST_TO', 'TEST_FROM', 'TEST_MSG', 'TEST_FIELD', 'TEST_DATE')");
```

The returned error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax.
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068)

Comment: @Quentin: what is the recommended replacement?

Comment: Follow the links through to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @Quentin: when will `mysql_query` functions no longer work on most servers?

Comment: A timeline hasn't been announced. mysql_* still doesn't support paramterized queries though, and they are the best defence against SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`to` and `from` are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You need to quote them (with backticks since they are field names). (It is worth getting into the habit of always quoting field names rather then trying to remember which are reserved).

Comment: also date is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Abu — It is, but you don't need to quote it. It comes under the list on the page that I linked to that is prefixed: *MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them*

Answer (score 3):

You have reserved words in your column names like - from, to. Use backticks to escape.

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (`to`, `from`, `msg`, `field`, `date`)  
  VALUES ('TEST_TO', 'TEST_FROM', 'TEST_MSG', 'TEST_FIELD', 'TEST_DATE')");
```

Note: mysql_query is deprecated. Use mysqli_query or PDO functions.